# Incomplete Type of Nested Class

Tags: c++

I have a code in the following form:

```
class Trie{
public:
    Trie( ) : root( new TrieNode( ) ){ };

    // Inserts a word into the trie.
    void insert( std::string word );

    // Returns if the word is in the trie.
    bool search( std::string word );

    // Returns if there is any word in the trie
    // that starts with the given prefix.
    bool startsWith( std::string prefix );

private:
    class TrieNode;
    std::unique_ptr<TrieNode> root;
};

class Trie::TrieNode{
public:
    TrieNode( ) : eow( false ){ };

    TrieNode* appendChar( char tar );

    void end( );

    bool isEnd( );

    TrieNode* getChar( char tar );

    int getInd( char tar );

private:
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<TrieNode>, 26> data;
    bool eow;                        // End of word
};
```

However, at the third line, `Trie(): root( new TrieNode() )`, compiler continue complains that `TrieNode` is incomplete. How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Try defining the class TrieNode inside the Trie class

Comment: You can't have `new TrieNode` at a point where `TrieNode` is incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `Trie`'s constructor after the `TrieNode` definition

```
class Trie::TrieNode{...}

// must be AFTTER the class Trie is fully defined
Trie::Trie( ) : root( new TrieNode( ) ){ };
```

otherwise the constructor of `Trie` needs the full definition of `TrieNode`, as it needs to construct a new object, hence your error.